# How use media query in react

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, jsx

How can I make a chek if media < 767 show ListTitleMobile

```
  render() {
        return (
            <div className="pokemonlist">
                    <ListTitle />
                    <ListTitleMobile/>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: There are no media queries or attempts to use queries in this question. Where is your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [react-media](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media) as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you) It is help